# Как организовать базу данных для миниатюр фотографий?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, thumbnails

Разрабатываю, для домашних нужд, фотохостинг. Для каждой фотографий будет до 7 миниатюр. Мне необходимо сохранять габариты и размер миниатюр. С учетом, пути, в итоге, получается 28 атрибутов. И это только по миниатюрам. Кроме этого, есть дополнительные 15 атрибутов, характеризующие фотографию. В итоге, 43 атрибута. Нам мой малый кругозор, это очень много.

Пришёл в голову альтернативный вариант, а именно, вынести миниатюры в другое отношение.

```
photos - id | otherAttr

thumbs - id | photo_id | path | width | height | size
```

Этот вариант удобен в выборке по габаритам, но он увеличивает базу данных многократно. При добавление 1000 фотографий (а их больше будет), в отношение thumbs будет 7000 строк.

Какой из этих вариантов самый оптимальный? Наверняка, есть и альтернатива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1000 фотографий и 7000 строк - это мааааааааааааааааааааааааааааленькая БД, даже для Mysql, так что не парься

Если параметры фотографии и миниатюр отличаются, то я просто создал бы 2 таблицы

> photos

и

> thumbs

как ты и описал

при этом для тех полей, по которым будет выполняться поиск (минимум для photo_id в таблице thumbs) я бы построил индексы. В итоге все должно работать быстро и не занимать очень уж много места

можно конечно извратиться и вместо пути хранить фотографии сразу в БД (через blob например)

Для твоих целей твоего решения более чем достаточно.

**P.S.**

если же и миниатюры и фотографии имеют одинаковые параметры (по идее это и то и то фотографии), то я бы все записал в одну таблицу, но добавил бы поле

> parent_id

и индексы по нему построил бы и все.
Такой подход вообще позволил бы дерево иметь - т.е. когда у миниатюр есть свои миниатюры (но это уже излишне конечно :) ).

Comment: Не делай акцент на 7000 строк. Это для примера =)

Я просто хотел показать, что в этой идее есть узкое место. Заполнив неимоверно отношение photos, что будет с thumbs ума не приложу.

В photos не будут храниться пути на какие либо фотографии. В отношение thumbs я предположил выносить не только миниатюры, но и саму фотографию. В photos останутся только атрибуты самого объекта.

Такой способ позволяет, в дальнейшем, отношение photos переименовать в items и использовать как для фото, так и для видео.

Comment: А это уже позволит объединять фото и видео в один альбом. Хранить комментарии к фото и видео в одном отношение.

Comment: Перед созданием БД стоит задать вопрос - что я хочу с данными делать, чаще записывать или выбирать, структура БД после создания будет почти неизменной или пользователи (в т.ч. начальник) будут каждый день выдавать новые хотелки и придется постоянно что-то докручивать. Если у тебя задача редкое пополнение-частая выборка и простые запросы, т.е. без слияний таблиц, перекрестных ссылок и т.д., то таблица параметров, таблица  объектов (как у тебя сейчас) легко и миллиард записей переварит.
Если не сложно - опиши вообще что ты хотел бы делать с данными и какие они у тебя должны быть.

Comment: Основная идея - просматривать и комментировать фотографии. Фотографии будут собираться в альбомах. В дальнейшем, добавить видео. Объединить два типа файлов и едином отношение. Акцент будет делаться на выборку. Добавление данных в систему будет проводиться, в основной массе, через консоль.

Comment: тогда скорее всего (чтобы не была излишне большой БД) нужно  таблицы - информация по изображениям/видео (если все атрибуты можно отнести и к изображениям и миниатюрам - то одна таблица, в которой будет поле parent_id, если атрибуты для изображений и видео отличаются - тогда таблица для видео, таблица для изображений, общая таблица где будет поле type) и таблица для комментариев (в основной таблице comment_id на первый комментарий, в таблице комментариев child_id и next_id для дерева комментариев например)

Comment: Чуть позже опубликую принятую схему. Возможно, вам покажется интересным.

Answer (score 0):

Для приложения фотогалереи определился со структурой базы данных.
Получилась лаконичная схема, с возможностью объединения двух типов файлов - фото и видео.

Приемущества:
    1) Без изворотов, разнотипные медиафайлы можно объединять в альбомы;
    2) Для комментариев и закладок достаточно по одному отношению (таблице);
    3) Миниатюры медиафайлов вынесены в отношение photos, что позволило схему привезти к 2НФ;
    4) Отношение items упростилось на 5 атрибутов.

В результате, такую схему оказалось проще модерировать. В приложение предусмотрена функция выбора миниатюры по габаритам, соответствующих структуре отображения. Например, при отображение галереи в стиле justfield, система ориентируется на высоту изображения, и подбирает файлы с похожим размером высоты. Это позволяет не загружать тяжеловесные файлы.

Недостатки:
    1) При добавление одной записи в items, в photos будет добавляться до 5 записей.

Сейчас сложно судить об этом недостатке. В скором времени, проверю этот пункт, записав в items от 1 млн. строк.[image: схема]
[image: результат]